# Obtaining kettle repository directory

Tags: pentaho, kettle

I am using a file-based kettle repository, which is checked into subversion. I would like to put a properties file in the repository an load this file in a job. To do this I would need to get hold of the repository directory within the job. Anyone know how I could do this?

Answer (score 0):

You can use a set variable job entry to acquire your properties, and pass a relative path for your file, e.g.

`${Internal.Job.Filename.Directory}/config.properties`

Comment: It should be noted that this only works when not using a repository - also see [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5654175/kettle-internal-job-filename-directory/14255710#14255710).